# B Spline Regression Penalty Matrix in Python

Tags: python, spline

Does anyone know of any Python function/packages which compute the penalty matrix for a given b spline basis? I.e. the matrix with entries $$\int B_i’’(u) B_j’’(u) du $$ where the $B_i$ are the given basis functions

Answer (score 0):

One option is the Python library [Scikit-fda](https://fda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Below is some code to generate a penalty matrix using a mock b-spline basis made with 10 equally spaced knots.

```py
import skfda
import numpy as np


# generate b-splines 
k = 10
degree = 3
knots = np.linspace(0, 1, k - degree)
bsplines = skfda.representation.basis.BSplineBasis(knots=knots, order=degree + 1)

# calculate penalty matrix
diffMatrixOrder = 2 
operator = skfda.misc.operators.LinearDifferentialOperator(diffMatrixOrder)
regularization = skfda.misc.regularization.L2Regularization(operator)
penalty_matrix = regularization.penalty_matrix(bsplines)

# To get the spline basis:
bspline_matrix = bsplines.to_basis().to_grid().data_matrix
```

Here is a comparison of a penalty matrix generated using [Scikit-fda](https://fda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (in Python) and another penalty matrix generated using the R [fda::bsplinepen](https://rdrr.io/cran/fda/man/bsplinepen.html) function.

[image: pen_matrix]

and the splines used:

[image: splines]

### Code:

```bash
pip install scikit-fda
pip install rpy2
```

(NOTE -- rpy2 is just for the Python Vs R comparison, you probably dont need it)

```py
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skfda
from matplotlib.colors import TwoSlopeNorm


def get_r_penalty_matrix(k, degree, diffMatrixOrder):
    """
    library(fda)
    knots = seq(from = 0, to = 1, length = k - degree + 1);
    nknots   = length(knots);
    basisobj = fda::create.bspline.basis(
        c(0, knots[nknots-1]), norder = degree + 1,
        nbasis = k - 1, breaks = knots[-nknots]);
    P = fda::bsplinepen(basisobj, Lfdobj = diffMatrixOrder)
    """
    importr('fda')
    robjects.r(f'k <- {k}')
    robjects.r(f'degree <- {degree}')
    robjects.r(f'diffMatrixOrder <- {diffMatrixOrder}')
    robjects.r('knots <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length = k - degree + 1)')
    robjects.r('nknots <- length(knots)')
    robjects.r(
        'basisobj <- fda::create.bspline.basis(c(0, knots[nknots-1]), norder = degree + 1, nbasis = k - 1, breaks = knots[-nknots])')
    robjects.r("plot(basisobj, knots=FALSE, las=1, lwd=2, main=sprintf('Num basis = %d' ,basisobj$nbasis))")
    robjects.r("savePlot('r_basisobj.png', type='png')")
    robjects.r('P <- fda::bsplinepen(basisobj, Lfdobj = 1)')
    p = robjects.r['P']
    return p / np.max(p)


def get_py_penalty_matrix(k, degree, diffMatrixOrder):
    knots = np.linspace(0, 1, k - degree)
    basis = skfda.representation.basis.BSplineBasis(knots=knots, order=degree + 1)
    basis.plot()
    plt.gcf().suptitle(f'Num basis = {len(basis)}')
    plt.savefig('python_basisobj.png')
    operator = skfda.misc.operators.LinearDifferentialOperator(diffMatrixOrder)
    regularization = skfda.misc.regularization.L2Regularization(operator)
    p = regularization.penalty_matrix(basis)
    return p / np.max(p)


def test_penalty_matrix():
    k = 10
    degree = 3
    diffMatrixOrder = 1
    r_p = get_r_penalty_matrix(k, degree, diffMatrixOrder)
    py_p = get_py_penalty_matrix(k, degree, diffMatrixOrder)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    for i, (label, matrix) in enumerate(zip(('r', 'python'), (r_p, py_p))):
        matrix = matrix / np.max(matrix)
        ax[i].set_title(label)
        norm = TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=matrix.min(), vcenter=0, vmax=matrix.max())
        im = ax[i].pcolor(matrix, ec='tab:gray', lw=0.005, cmap='bwr', norm=norm, antialiased=False)
        fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax[i], orientation='horizontal')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('penalty_matrix.png')
    assert np.allclose(r_p, py_p, atol=1e-10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_penalty_matrix()
```

[See the related Sckit-fda git-issue for this.](https://github.com/GAA-UAM/scikit-fda/issues/210)